# I want to check only one radio button i selected in a list of 7 radio buttons in Selenium

Tags: html, selenium

Here is the Html Code:

```
label for="experience">Years of Experience:</label
input name="experience" type="radio" value="one">
input name="experience" type="radio" value="two">
input name="experience" type="radio" value="three">
```

.......

and so on"
In this i want to check only 1 radio Button is Selected Using Selenium

```
@Test

WebElement val = driver.findElement(By.name("experience"));
List<WebElement>radios = val.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type ='radio']"));

for(WebElement radio : radios) {

if(radio.getAttribute("value").contains("four")){
radio.click();
String bt = (radio.getAttribute("value") + "  " + radio.isSelected());
              Assert.assertEquals(bt, "four  true");
              System.out.println(bt);

    }
```

With this i m passing a particular value, I want it be automatically checked that 1 of the radio button is selected.

Thanks

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Instead of formatting the relevant _HTML_ update the question with text based unedited _HTML_ for proper analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `xpath` to `//input[@type='radio' and @checked]` to get the `List` of radio buttons that is selected and verify if the size of the `List` is equal to 1. If it is 1 that means that only 1 radio button is selected.

Comment: //input[@type='radio' and @checked] Tried using this but doesn't work well :(

Comment: What's the issue with that?